# Install FosuserBundle without composer.phar

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I use now symfony 2.5 and i would use FosuserBundle but i have problem in composer.phar, is there another way to install this Bundle without using composer?

I would like to install the composer.phar in my symfony application I download the call since https://github.com/composer/composer.

but when I run the command:

```
php composer.phar install
```

i have this in my consol :

```
Problem 1

-Installation request for symfony/icu v1.2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.1]

-symfony/icu v1.2.1 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the extension providing it.

Problem 2

-symfony/symfony v2.5.0 requires symfony/icu ~1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.1].

-symfony/symfony v2.5.0 requires symfony/icu ~1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.1].

-symfony/icu v1.2.1 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked  library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure have the extension providing it.

- Installation request for symfony/symfony v2.5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
```

any help please !!

Comment: Better post your composer problem here...

Comment: You could download the package and put it in your `/src` directory but the best thing would be to sort your composer issues out.

Comment: i have to update a php intl extension. but the command doesn't work !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you used https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md
$ php composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0@dev" this problem,
used in composer.json

```
   "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev"
```

Try used

$ php composer update.